# Identifying which values do NOT match a table row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, except

I would like to be able to easily check which unique identifiers do not exist in a table, of those supplied in a query.

To better explain, here's what I would do now, to check which IDs of the list "1, 2, 3, 4" do not exist in a table:

1. `SELECT * FROM dbo."TABLE" WHERE "ID" IN ('1','2','3','4')`, let's say the table contains no row with ID 2.
2. Dump the results into Excel
3. Run a VLOOKUP on the original list that searches for each list value in the result list.
4. Any VLOOKUP that results in an `#N/A` is on a value that did not occur in the table.

I'm thinking there's got to be a better way to do this. I'm looking, ideally, for something like

> List to check -> Query on table to check -> Members of list not in table

Comment: Please don't make us guess the version of SQL Server?

Comment: NOT IN / EXISTS? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists

Comment: Apologies. [edited] It's old. The problem with NOT IN is it'll return everything else in the table...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`EXCEPT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx):

```
SELECT * FROM
  (values (1),(2),(3),(4)) as T(ID)
EXCEPT
SELECT ID 
FROM [TABLE];
```

See [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b99e4/5/1).

---

The `values` constructor will only work on SQL Server 2008 or later. For 2005, use

```
SELECT 'value'
UNION SELECT 'value'
```

as detailed in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1564973/152891).

Comment: Whoops, should have specified. What if ID is a varchar?

Comment: @NReilingh then redesign your DB :)  but it should work the same I think

Comment: I keep getting `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'values'.` when running `SELECT * FROM (values ('search string'),('other string')) as T(ID)`

Comment: Your syntax works fine for me in SQL Server 2008r2 - I pasted your comment in and it ran.

Comment: I'm on 2005. Christ.

Comment: You can use the `SELECT 1 AS ID UNION ...  EXCEPT ...`: [fiddle-2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b99e4/8)

Comment: Just figured that out! I'm going to suggest an edit and accept.

Answer (score 6):

I would build up a table variable or temp table containing the IDs that you're searching for... then use Remus's solution, minus the 2008 syntactic sugar:

```
declare @t table (ID int)
insert into @t values (1)
insert into @t values (2)
insert into @t values (3)
insert into @t values (4)
insert into @t values (5)

select ID from @t
except
select ID
from [Table];
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm now a couple years wiser (and have a newer SQL Server) than when I asked this question, so to celebrate the Famous Question badge I got for asking this, here's what I would do now. (I don't think I've ever used the `EXCEPT` operator since.)

I would say the `LEFT JOIN` method below is more useful than `EXCEPT` since you can compose it with other joins without needing a CTE.

```
SELECT v.val
  FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)) v (val)
    LEFT JOIN dbo.SomeTable t
      ON t.id = v.val
  WHERE t.id IS NULL;
```